# ¿Como usar recursividad para ordenar listas y no caer en el error de recursividad infinita?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, funciones, recursión

Estoy aprendiendo sobre recursividad en Python. Entiendo que para esto, la idea es que pensar un caso base , que sea simple de resolver y luego el paso recursivo que llama a la misma  función  pero ya con el problema mas pequeño, y que este se va a ir acercando al caso base. Pero antes de el paso recursivo tiene que estar pensada una condición , que cuando se cumpla el programa se detenga y me retorne el resultado esperado , sin continuar en una recursividad infinita. Entiendo algunos ejemplos con el de cuenta regresiva u algunos otros ejemplos, pero no estoy lográndolo con este ejercicio de listas. Agradecido de orientacion sobre como pensar para resolver esto y armar el codigo. Gracias.

Tienes una lista de listas. Cada lista interior contiene listas o strings. Por ejemplo, la lista se podría ver de la siguiente forma:

```
lista = [
          [['a'], ['b', 'c']],
          ['d', ['e']]
]
```

Deberás definir la función recursiva en_orden(lista, ordenada), la cuál recibe como parámetro una lista en el formato anterior y una lista vacía. La función deberá llenar la lista ordenada de la siguiente manera:

Primero se debe agregar (append) a ordenada , la lista recibida, y luego deben agregarse a continuación cada una de las listas dentro de lista.

```
lista =  [['a'], [['b'], 'c']]
ordenada = []
en_orden(lista, ordenada)
for x in ordenada:
    print(x)
```

> Deberá imprimir:

```
[['a'], [['b'], 'c']] ['a'] [['b'], 'c'] ['b']
```

> Ayuda: La instrucción type(x) retorna el tipo de la variable x. Por
> ejemplo, para saber si una variable es del tipo str, puedes hacer la
> comparaci%C3%B3n type(x) == str. Lo mismo se puede hacer con el tipo
> list.

Esto es lo que estoy intentando entre otros intentos , pero no estaría funcionándome.

```
 def en_orden(lista, ordenada):        
    ordenada=[]
    ordenada.append(lista)
    for x in ordenada:
        if type(x)== list:
            print(x)   
            en_orden(lista[1:], ordenada)  
        else:
            return ordenada.append(lista[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El caso base es la lista que no contiene otras listas, que sólo contiene strings.
No tendremos recursividad infinita si sólo llamamos a `en_orden` cuando alguno de los elementos de `lista` sea de tipo `list`.

Iteramos la lista que recibimos.
Para los elementos que sean listas llamamos a `en_orden`.
Nos aseguramos de que `en_orden` siempre recibe una lista en el primer argumento y por eso siempre hacemos el `append`.
Los que no sean listas serán strings y no queremos iterarlas:

```py
def en_orden(lista: list, ordenada: list):
    ordenada.append(lista)

    for element in lista:
        if type(element) == list:
            en_orden(element, ordenada)
```

---

Existe un caso en el que la recursión es infinita.
Imagina una lista que se contiene a sí misma.
Te puede parecer un ejemplo muy marciano, pero se puede construir fácilmente:

```py
lista = ['a']
lista[0] = lista
```

Si quisieras escribir tu función a prueba de estas recursiones infinitas basta con escribir justo al inicio de la función:

```py
def en_orden(lista: list, ordenada: list):
    if any(sub_lista for sub_lista in ordenada
           if id(sub_lista) == lista):
        return
```

Aunque aún hay casos que pueden llevarte a una recursión infinita:

```py
ordenada = []
en_orden(ordenada, ordenada)
```

Comment: Tu comentario es muy claro.  Esta manera de expresar la solución es resulta simple y mas mas natural. Me llama la atención el cambio al llamar la función y cambiar lista por element.